# Update a md-list dynamically from angular

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have a md-list with md-whiteframe and I would like add dynamically a new element into the list without use ng-repeat but directly from angular.

Have you a solution to add dynamically material design element in other?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple solution is to use ng-repeat and "track by element.id" to refresh only the new element in the list.

Comment: Yes, this is the 'Angular way' of dynamically adding items to a list. You could of course use jQuery/jqlite via element.find() if you didn't want to use ng-repeat for some reason. But that is not recommended. You should probably mark this as the answer.